# Bitcoin: How to check payment received on many bitcoin addresses

Tags: php, json, payment, bitcoin

I have one bitcoin address that should send some bitcoin to 3 bitcoin addresses. Which API should I use in order to check if  all address has received BTC ?

Comment: The best API is still to use the Bitcoin Core JSON RPC API

Answer (score 4):

You could use Blocktrails API and with the "Address transactions" you can view all incoming and outgoing transactions amd based on the number of conformations check whether the recipent received the coins.

[Checkout their API here](https://www.blocktrail.com/api/docs/lang/php#api_ref)